# Alternative to XSD.EXE in LINQ-to-XML?

Tags: c#, schema, linq-to-xml, xsd.exe

Can LINQ-to-XML be used in a generic way to accomlish the intent of XSD.EXE, thus avoiding the usage of XSD.EXE

Comment: Please specify which of the features of XSD.EXE you want to replace.

Answer (score -1):

XSD2Code @ codeplex.
I am using it in my project and works like a charm.

Link: http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/

Comment: -1: no doubt a great tool, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @John: Agreed. I think I just went by the title missing LINQ part.